# How to make input `type=file` to accept only images React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
<Input
  id="image"
  type="file"
  accept="image/*"
  onChange={(event) =>
    getBase64(event.target.files[0])
      .then((file) => this.setState({ image: file })
  )}
/>
```

**But it does accept other files too**, what should I change to make it accept only images?

Comment: What do you mean by "it does accept other files too" and how is this related to React only? Do you want to validate the file type before uploading it to your server?

Comment: React has an [`<input>`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) element, not `<Input>` - you must be using some library that ignores the `accept` prop. Which library are you using?

Answer (score 6):

To set the `accept` attribute on an `<Input />` you need to use `inputProps`like this

```
<Input type="file" inputProps={{ accept: 'image/*' }} />
```

*EDIT*
Looking at this some months later and reading @Aprillions comment I think it would be good to clarify this is Material-UI and not pure React

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be that you have passed or modified the props after changed the `accept` attribute. so, you have a solution or that. change the attribute order you passed. that means you can pass the `accept` attribute as the last attribute, like below.

```
<Input
 id="image"
 type="file"
 onChange={event =>
  getBase64(event.target.files[0]).then(file =>
   this.setState({ image: file })
 )
 accept="image/*"
}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

File inputs have an `accept` attribute which you can use for this ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file)).

Comment: you  mean  this, accept="image/*"  even after  this attribute  it does allow to select other files

Comment: @AmarThapa that will specify that only files with an image MIME type can be uploaded